# Alert close button position out of control

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap1w9.png) is what the alert and alert close button should look like on the Bootstrap website, but when I adopted it to my website, it becomes like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b8tF.png)

I tried to modify the bootstrap.min.css file, but it doesn't seem to work. I tried to upload it to my VM, and vim it. It was modified, but Inspector still showed no.

Here is what I typed:

```
<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable" role="alert" style="z-index:9999;position:relative;top:100px">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" style="text-align:right;"><span aria-hidden = "true">&times;</span></button>
{{message}}
</div>
```

Also, I am sure I include js.
Anyone can help?

Comment: The code you posted works just fine with correct alignment. You have something else which is interfering with the alert. Please post complete code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `position: relative` is related to the problem, but it's very difficult to analyze the problem without a context.
I would like to encourage you to use the developer console e.g. in Chrome.
You'll find a short intro here:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/